# получить ID оборудования python

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить id оборудования в диспетчере устройств при помощи python
для дальнейшего поиска драйверов.

Comment: 1. посмотреть в какой ветке реестра
2. изучить как в питоне вызывать данные из реестра

Comment: `$ lspci | less`

Comment: Есть утилита devcon.exe, вроде она в Windows SDK находится. Конечно, вопрос надо задавать подробнее: какой тип устройства интересует (не факт, что именно на PCIe), какие именно ID-шники. Из реестра тоже можно, но это чуть больше изучать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получение id:

```py
id = os.system("WMIC PATH Win32_PnPSignedDriver
GET DeviceName,DeviceID /format:list > utf-8 > %Temp%\\id_file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще нужна спец. Прога dmidecode

```py
subprocess.Popen('dmidecode.exe -s system-uuid'.split())
```

Но можно и через UUID чекнуть

```py
import uuid
print(uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode()))
```